# Want to open a PDF file in Titanium Studio on Android Application

Tags: android, titanium

I want to open PDF file directly on PDF viewer in Android,
I don't want to use google docs for that neither it should  open on browser.

can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this code:

```
try {
    var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('your.pdf');
    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action: Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
        type: 'application/pdf',
        data: f.getNativePath()
    }));
}
catch (err) {
    var alertDialog = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
        title: 'No PDF Viewer',
        message: 'We tried to open a PDF but failed. Do you want to search the marketplace for a PDF viewer?',
        buttonNames: ['Yes','No'],
        cancel: 1
    });
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        if (evt.index == 0) {
            Ti.Platform.openURL('http://search?q=pdf');
        }
    });
}
```

taken from here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/72361/open-pdf-file-on-android